# SLURM - How can I determine what specific CPUs a job is using?

Tags: cluster-computing, cpu, slurm, sbatch

I'm working on a tool for monitoring the jobs currently running on a cluster (19 nodes, 40 cores). Is there any way to determine which specific cpus each job in the slurm queue is using? I'm getting data using 'pidstat', 'mpstat', and 'ps -eFj', that tells me what processes are running on a particular core, but have no way to relate those process IDs to the Job IDs that Slurm uses. 'scontrol show job' gives a lot of information, but not specific cpu allocation. Is there any way to do this?

Heres the code that collects the data:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import threading
import time

def scan():
  data = [[None, None, None] for i in range(19)]
  def mpstat(node):
    if(node == 1):
      output = subprocess.check_output(['mpstat', '-P', 'ALL', '1', '1'])
    else:
      output = subprocess.check_output(['ssh', 'node' + str(node), 'mpstat', '-P', 'ALL', '1', '1'])
    data[node - 1][0] = output
  def pidstat(node):
    if(node == 1):
      output = subprocess.check_output(['pidstat', '1', '1'])
    else:
      output = subprocess.check_output(['ssh', 'node' + str(node), 'pidstat', '1', '1'])
    data[node - 1][1] = output
  def ps(node):
    if(node == 1):
      output = subprocess.check_output(['ps', '-eFj'])
    else:
      output = subprocess.check_output(['ssh', 'node' + str(node), 'ps', '-eFj'])
    data[node - 1][2] = output
  threads = [[None, None, None] for i in range(19)]
  for node in range(1, 19 + 1):
    threads[node - 1][0] = threading.Thread(target=mpstat, args=(node,))
    threads[node - 1][0].start()
    threads[node - 1][1] = threading.Thread(target=pidstat, args=(node,))
    threads[node - 1][1].start()
    threads[node - 1][2] = threading.Thread(target=ps, args=(node,))
    threads[node - 1][2].start()
  while True:
    alive = [[not t.isAlive() for t in n]  for n in threads]
    alive = [t for n in alive for t in n]
    if(all(alive)):
      break
    time.sleep(1.0)
  return(data)
```

Comment: is the "monitoring" provided by slurm not enough? If your system is using cgroups, maybe you can get the information directly from the cgroups instead of looking at all the processes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using the `-d` flag you can get the CPU_IDs of the job on each node as shown below.

```
$ scontrol show job -d $SLURM_JOBID
JobId=1 JobName=bash
   UserId=USER(UID) GroupId=GROUP(GID) MCS_label=N/A
   Priority=56117 Nice=0 Account=account QOS=interactive
   JobState=RUNNING Reason=None Dependency=(null)
   Requeue=1 Restarts=0 BatchFlag=0 Reboot=0 ExitCode=0:0
   DerivedExitCode=0:0
   RunTime=00:00:10 TimeLimit=02:00:00 TimeMin=N/A
   SubmitTime=2019-04-12T17:34:11 EligibleTime=2019-04-12T17:34:11
   StartTime=2019-04-12T17:34:12 EndTime=2019-04-12T19:34:12 Deadline=N/A
   PreemptTime=None SuspendTime=None SecsPreSuspend=0
   Partition=defq AllocNode:Sid=node2:25638
   ReqNodeList=(null) ExcNodeList=(null)
   NodeList=node1
   BatchHost=node2
   NumNodes=1 NumCPUs=2 NumTasks=1 CPUs/Task=2 ReqB:S:C:T=0:0:*:*
   TRES=cpu=2,mem=17600M,node=1
   Socks/Node=* NtasksPerN:B:S:C=0:0:*:* CoreSpec=*
     Nodes=node1 CPU_IDs=12-13 Mem=17600 GRES_IDX=
   MinCPUsNode=2 MinMemoryCPU=8800M MinTmpDiskNode=0
   Features=(null) DelayBoot=00:00:00
   Gres=(null) Reservation=(null)
   OverSubscribe=OK Contiguous=0 Licenses=(null) Network=(null)
   Command=bash
   WorkDir=/home/USER
   Power=
```

If this information is not enough you may find useful the output of `scontrol pidinfo PID`

```
$ scontrol pidinfo 43734
Slurm job id 21757758 ends at Fri Apr 12 20:15:49 2019
slurm_get_rem_time is 6647
```

Comment: This shows how many CPUs are allocated to a job, but not what the actual CPUs are. (Doesn't match ps or pidstat output)

Comment: `Nodes=node1 CPU_IDs=12-13 Mem=17600 GRES_IDX=`

Comment: On my system, those aren't the actual CPUs. Running 'pidstat 1 1' and looking at the CPU column confirms this.

Comment: As mentioned on the slurm webpage (https://slurm.schedmd.com/cpu_management.html)

A NOTE ON CPU NUMBERING
The number and layout of logical CPUs known to Slurm is described in the node definitions in slurm.conf. This may differ from the physical CPU layout on the actual hardware. For this reason, Slurm generates its own internal, or "abstract", CPU numbers. These numbers may not match the physical, or "machine", CPU numbers known to Linux.

Comment: See the edit in the answer about `scontrol pidinfo` which may provide another way to match `pids` to jobs